metadata driven DQ validation for multiple tables dynamically
There are multiple tables in the config/metadata table. These tables need to be validated for DQ rules.

Natural Key / Business Key /Primary Key cannot be null or blank.
Natural Key/Primary Key cannot be duplicate.
Join columns missing values
Business specific rule

How do we validate the above rules dynamically for the tables configured in the metadata driven table using Pyspark
How the data validation rule engine need to be build using pyspark.
Example
There are 2 tables Employee & Address.
So a generic function will be written which will verify the EmployeeId not null/blank and for Address table Addressline1 cannot be null/blank.
